# ByteStringCoder for reading data in Apache Beam

Tags: apache-beam, dataflow

I am trying to read data with version 2.4.0 of Apache Beam using the standard `TextIO.read()`. The data has to be read as a ByteString.

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem like Apache Beam supports `.withCoder()` in the same way Dataflow does. I can't seem to find an alternative way to introduce a coder. Furthermore, it seems like `ByteStringCoder` is no longer included in the coders of Apache Beam.

What's the best way to get the same result of Dataflow's `.withCoder(ByteStringCoder.of())` with the latest version of Apache Beam? Coders are still present in Apache Beam so there has to be some way to use them.

Answer (score 1):

`ByteStringCoder` is located in `beam-sdks-java-extensions-protobuf` module so you need to include dependency

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.beam/beam-sdks-java-extensions-protobuf

As for the `TextIO`: It uses `StringUtf8Coder` so you probably need to write your own BoundedSource/UnboundedSource.
And then use:

`pipeline.apply(Read.from(yourCreatedSource))`

You could take inspiration of current `TextSource`, where you can **probably** only change type `String` of `FileBasedSource` for `ByteString`.

https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/TextSource.java